# angular load and bind model into textarea?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, textarea

I have a `load()` function in my controller, which I use to load new text into textarea. But, I was hoping it can include model i.e.`{{hostname}}` in the below example. But, it's just a dead text in braces.

How do I bind it?

```
$scope.load = function (data, filename) {
        $("#textarea").text("Here it is {{hostname}}");
    };
```

Will triggering digest cycle work ?

Comment: can you also provide your html?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `$scope.load()` in your controller as well.

```
$scope.load = function (data, filename) {
    $("#textarea").text("Here it is {{hostname}}");
};

$scope.load();
```

Can you provide a plunkr?

Comment: can't access plunkr for some reason right now. But of course my html includes load button like this <button ng-click="load()">Load</button>

Comment: @irom Where is `hostname` defined? If it's on the scope, then do `$("#textarea").text("Here it is " + $scope.hostname`)